# Ember data and relationships. Performance

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is my second Ember Application, and the following problem has been a reoccurring theme.

I am using the Canary build of both Ember js and Ember data with query params enabled.

Say we have the following relationships:

- A has many B
- A has many C
- A has many D
- A has many E

Model B, C, D, E are huge models and resource heavy for rendering. So loading them ALL the time is not optimal.

Say if my application has a dashboard that allows for a quick glance of the state of the application, and it focuses on model A. I don't need to display anything from B, C, D, E. So the JSON will not return the relationship ID array from the `example.com/api/a` endpoint.

And if the user clicks to the `show` route of model A then **How should I load models B, C, D, E?**

Thanks All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bill, I answered your question on the Ember discussion forum, but I'm going to copy the answer here as well, just so the question is answered.

> I've been using a very old version of Ember Data for a long time, and
>   I just updated to the latest version a few days ago. Because of this,
>   take what I say with a grain of salt. :) But I believe that Ember Data
>   only loads records/relationships lazily. So you should return the IDs
>   for B, C, D, E along with the JSON for A, and then Ember Data should
>   load the records for them automatically as soon as you reference them.
>
> EDIT: Almost forgot. You must include the async: true option for this
>   to work.
>
> ```
> App.A = DS.Model.extend({
>     b: DS.hasMany('b', { async: true });
> });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more trouble than its worth... Ember convention would be to load A with it's relationship IDs to B,C,D,E. If you're caching your responses on the server, this should be faster the second time around.

Otherwise, you might be able to change the `ajaxPrefilter` before your request on the dashboard page to have some header that you can use in your server to change its default response.

```
Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
 jqXHR.setRequestHeader('no_relationship_ids', 'true');
});
```

Then in your show page, you'll always have to `.reload()` the model before rendering (and obviously not include the above header).